# Streamreader initialization with a text file that has an empty line each other line

Tags: c#, exception, streamreader, using, initialization

I'm facing a quite curious problem. I'm trying to initialize a streamreader with a file name and an encoding parameter but my code fails due to the fact the file has an empty line each other line contained.

What I'm trying to do is to read the lines in a list. If the file does not contain empty lines then the code executes sucessfuly.

i'm initalizing the reader like this

```
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, encoding))
            {
               //do stuff...
            }
```

Any thoughts as of how I could perform the operation mentioned above ? This is for an automated process, so no manual tampering with the file can be performed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `bool hasAnyEmptyLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Any(l => l.Length == 0);` or maybe `File.ReadAllLines(filename).Where(l => l.Length != 0).ToList()` to get only the non-empty lines. No reason to muck about with explicit `StreamReader`s unless you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the enconding of the file was messed up when I saved it using Notepad++ (without altering anything on the file, simply clicking save) and the Streamreader did not like it. I can parse it correctly now (if do not click on "save" accidentally) and i can handle the empty lines using

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName)){
while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{
    // read every line
    line = sr.ReadLine(); 

    // if line is empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim(' '))) // if you want to handle a line with a space as empty use trim for spaces
    {
        //... do something
    }
}
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the above solution does not work. The program throws an exception when it tries to execute the "using" clause. If i place another file or the same file without empty lines between the program works as expected. Is there another way to handle the matter ?

Comment: Hi, 
in my code i control if the file exists and i have a try-catch with following catches.
But within one year runtime i couldn't get much exceptions, none of these occurred after inserting empty lines.

'catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Error in file.");
}
catch (Exception exc) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("message:\n\n" + exc.Message + "\n\n\n" + "stack:\n\n" + exc.StackTrace, "an unexpected error occured");
}'

Comment: After a bit of thorough digging, apparently the reason why this is happening is most likely due to the encoding of the incoming file. I'll check it out and let you know.